# Macro to update filter on pivot to include all but "Blank" while leaving field settings as is

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I need a macro to select the Row Label filter and select all but "Blank." The last condition is, I need the macro to leave field settings as is: namely, I need the "Show items with no data" to remain unchecked.

We tried .showallitems=true but this modified the field settings to show items with no data.

Also tried pivotitem.visible=true but nothing happened.

Comment: Assume the possible row label items after pivot.refreshall are unknown. Thus, I cannot manually activate filters one by one with a macro. It needs to show all except blank.

Comment: Is this an OLAP/PowerPivot PivotTable, or a 'traditional' one?

Comment: non OLAP. Below answer is sufficient. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fire up the Macro recorder, then clear the filter, and deselect blank. That will give you the code you need.

For a non OLAP PivotTable, it will be as simple as this:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("test")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With
```